# How to concatenate a String and expression in JEXL

Tags: java, jexl

I am using JEXL http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/ to evaluate Strings.

I tried the following code

```
        String jexlExp = "'some text ' + output?'true':'false'";
        JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
        Expression e = jexl.createExpression(jexlExp);

        JexlContext jc = new MapContext();
        jc.set("output", false);

        Object x = e.evaluate(jc);
        System.out.println(x);
```

It is evaluating the expression to a wrong result. When I try to concat two Strings it works well. It is not working when I try to concat a string and expression.

So, how do I concatenate a string and expression in JEXL?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Are you getting an error?  Incorrect result?  What version of JEXL are you using?  I don't get a ParseException with 2.1.1.

Comment: I am using version 2.1.1 . I am getting wrong result

Comment: @rgettman , I am not getting ParseException now. But it is evaluating the expression to a wrong result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that JEXL is performing the concatenation of `'some text'` and `output` before the ternary operator `?:` is performed.

With your original expression, `'some text ' + output?'true':'false'`, I get an output of `true`.  I'm not entirely sure why `'some text ' + false` yields `true`, but there must be some kind of implicit conversion to `boolean` going on here.

Removing the ternary operator, using `'some text ' + output`, I get `some text false`.

Placing parentheses in the original expression to explicitly express what's happening, I can duplicate the output of `true` with the expression `('some text ' + output)?'true':'false'`.

Placing parentheses around the ternary operator, I can get the ternary operator to operate first and get the output `some text false` with the expression `'some text ' + (output?'true':'false')`.

This occurs because the ternary operator `?:` has lower precedence than the `+` operator in JEXL, matching Java's operator precedence.  Adding parentheses in the proper place force the execution of the `?:` operator first.